# Can I use a cfqueryparam tag in a SELECT clause of a query

Tags: mysql, sql, coldfusion

I'm trying to prevent my code from being injected and was wondering if I can write something like:

```
<cfquery name="queryName" dbtype="query">
SELECT <cfqueryparam cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' value='#temp#'>
FROM table
</cfquery>
```

I keep getting errors though

Comment: post your error

Comment: Yes, you can pass a variable in the select clause, but the database treats that as a constant value. If you are trying to dynamically select a column using your variable, you can't use `cfqueryparam` for that. You should instead sanitize the variable before execution to only allow known columns, and throw an error if it doesn't match.

Comment: Where you can and can't use query parameters depends to a certain extent on the database engine.  I don't use MySQL so I don't know about that one.

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind that there may be exploits other than SQLi that can make it through a cfqueryparam. Also, I belive you need to alias your SELECT variable, otherwise you won't be able to do anything with it.    For details on cfqueryparam: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfqueryparam.html

Comment: And I'm not sure because I can't test right now, but the way it's written, I believe you could still pass an invalid value to cause an error to get details about your query and database. Definitely error trap that. And if your <table> is a set value and #temp# is a set list of column names, you may as well whitelist for valid values and not bother with the cfqueryparam.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to run ad-hoc queries. This is a VERY bad idea. As @beloitdavisja noted, you need to clean up the variable from a list of known columns and throw an error if nothing matches.